# How to conditionally show a dropdown option in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a list of options called `header` to show in a dropdown list. I also have another list, `table_settings['tags']`, and I want the i'th element of `header` in the dropdown list if the i'th element of `table_settings['tags']` is `'Num'`.

Currently my code is:

```
<div *ngIf="header">
    <select (change)-"selectTarget($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let option of header; let i=index" value="{{i}}">
            <ng-template *ngIf="table_settings['tags'][{{i}}]=='Num'">
                {{ option }}
            </ng-template>
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But this is throwing all sorts of errors at the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation ({{}}) allows you to incorporate calculated value(strings) into the text between HTML element tags and attribute assignments. 
In your case, you don't need to calculate anything as you already have `i` handy.

***Solution***

```
<div *ngIf="header">
<select (change)-"selectTarget($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of header; let i=index" value="{{i}}">
        <ng-template *ngIf="table_settings['tags'][i]=='Num'">
            {{ option }}
        </ng-template>
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: In this case empty options are generated when the condition is not true. How to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
*ngIf="table_settings['tags'][i]=='Num'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf="header">
<select (change)-"selectTarget($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of header; let i=index" value="{{i}}">
        <ng-template *ngIf="table_settings['tags'][i]=='Num'">
            {{ option }}
        </ng-template>
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="header">
    <select (change)-"selectTarget($event)">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let option of header; let i=index" value="{{i}}">
            <option *ngIf="table_settings['tags'][i]=='Num'">
                {{ option }}
            </option>
        </ng-container>
    </select>
<div>
```